# how can I define python class with list attribute and the class constructor that accept variable arguments?

Tags: python

How can I define a python attribute as a class? I want to define a Python class that instantiate the objects that are list type. I can do that using `__init__` and a class method, but I'm looking for a way to avoid using a method. 
Second question is that I'm wondering if I can define a class with a constructor that accept variable arguments (e.g. to use this class to instantiate objects with different No of indexes ([4,5,6] and [1,2,3,4,7]).
I've copied my code below.
Thanks for your help :)

```py
    class SuperList(list):
        def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
        def My_list(self):
            return [self.a, self.b, self.c]
    obj1 = SuperList(1, 2, 3)
    List1 = obj1.My_list()
    List1.append(8)
    print(List1)
```

Comment: How is this different than a regular list?

Comment: @Tomerikoo The SuperList class inherits from inbuilt `<class 'list>` and can be useful for creating custom methods without overwriting inbuilt class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve with the "class generated list" but find below one example that may give you a better understanding.

As you are inheriting from `list`, just by doing the following you would have a custom list implementation:

```
class SuperList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(args)

list1 = SuperList(1, 2, 3)
list1.append(8)
print(list1)

list2 = SuperList(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9)
list2.append(999)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
class SuperList(list):
    def __init__(self,*a):
        self.myList = list(a)
    def My_list(self):
        return self.myList
```

This works for multiple argument

```py
obj1 = SuperList(1, 2, 54, 3)
print(obj1.My_list())
```